# Java Swing dynamic loading of classes into panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox

My program looks like this!

[image]

I want to have the bottom part dynamically load a frame into the bottom frame depending on the item selected in the ComboBox. For example, if the first item is selected I want a panel from the PresentValue.java file displayed. The idea is that I have one java file for each selection that displays what I design in its respective java file.

[image]

[image]

These two java files should be put into the "bottom" box from my first screenshot, depending on the selection from the combobox.

I'm more used to Android programming and there I would simple call the replace method from fragments to swap out the fragment loaded... looking for the analogy here.

```
final JComboBox selectorBox = new JComboBox(selection);
    selectorBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int selectionID = selectorBox.getSelectedIndex();

        }
    });
```

but cant find a way to do what I want to do. Please explain.

Comment: Load a frame into itself.. please explain..

Comment: see edit, i need the bottom part to change dynamically depending on what is selcted in the box

Comment: What is `PresentValue.java` ? is it a subclass of JPanel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each Java file that you have, the output of that Java file should be a `JPanel`.  Not a `JFrame`.

Before you display anything, execute all of the Java files you have.  Create all of the possible `JPanel`s.

Create your JFrame in your GUI, then use the remove and add methods of `JFrame` to remove or add the desired `JPanel`.

Here's an example from one of my GUI's.

```
public void updatePartControl() {
    Thread thread = new CountdownThread(model, this, displayPanel);
    thread.start();

    frame.remove(alarmPanel.getPanel());
    frame.add(displayPanel.getPanel());
    frame.validate();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setBounds(getBounds());
}
```

The setBounds method resets the bounds if the display `JPanel` is bigger or smaller than the alarm `JPanel`.

Your application should have one `JFrame`.  You use multiple `JPanel`s to create your GUI.

Comment: made some edits that should make it clearer what I need. Please advise

Answer (score 3):

Changing the bottom component will depend on the layout manager that are using. [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is purpose designed for swapping panels.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
   int selectionID = selectorBox.getSelectedIndex();
   if (selectionID == 0) {
      cardLayout.show(basePanel, SELECTED_1);
   } 
   // handle other selections

}
```

Comment: made some edits that should make it clearer what I need. Please advise